# How to Distributable Artifact/Classifier Jars : Complaining of missing pom file

Tags: java, maven, classification

Project background; large amounts of JNI projects for my group.  Looking to simplify the build/release strategies as the JNI projects themselves have dependency chains.

Used a model similar to here:  http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/maven-users/200706.mbox/%3C56761.84.233.182.145.1181035390.squirrel@www.sharp.fm%3E as a prototype that works well.  A distribution module adds the appropriate jars and the classifier is used.  Example final jar would be CiscoJ-dist-unix-amd64.jar.

Problem I'm hitting appears that install creates the project pom but attempting to use the classifier jar in a project, its is looking for the pom file matching the classifier; thus from above its looking for J-dist-unix-amd64.pom.  The only pom that exists is of course the project pom J-dist.pom.

**[WARNING]**

> The POM for com.cisco.ciscossl:CiscoJ-dist:jar:unix-amd64:1.00 is missing, no
>   dependency information available [DEBUG] Dependency collection stats:
>   {ConflictMarker.analyzeTime=1, ConflictMarker.markTime=0,
>   ConflictMarker.nodeCount=4, ConflictIdSorter.graphTime=0,
>   ConflictIdSorter.topsortTime=1, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCount=3,
>   ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCycleCount=0, ConflictResolver.totalTime=2,
>   ConflictResolver.conflictItemCount=3,
>   DefaultDependencyCollector.collectTime=290,
>   DefaultDependencyCollector.transformTime=6}

In project attempting to build with architecture dependent information.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.cisco.ciscossl</groupId>
      <artifactId>CiscoJ-dist</artifactId>
      <classifier>${os.family}-${os.arch}</classifier>
      <version>1.00</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

According to this; http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/pom-does-not-get-installed-if-classifier-used-td120388.html; it should be fixed with my version of maven (3.1.1).

Pom File of Project

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion> 
  <groupId>com.cisco.ciscossl.CiscoJ</groupId>
  <artifactId>CiscoJ-dist</artifactId>
  <version>1.00</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <parent>
    <groupId>com.cisco.ciscossl</groupId>
    <artifactId>CiscoJ</artifactId>
    <version>1.00</version>
  </parent>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>${pom.groupId}</groupId>
      <artifactId>CiscoJUtils</artifactId>
      <version>1.00</version>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>${pom.groupId}</groupId>
      <artifactId>CiscoJCE</artifactId>
      <version>1.00</version>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>${pom.groupId}</groupId>
      <artifactId>CiscoJSafeC</artifactId>
      <version>1.00</version>
      <classifier>${os.family}-${os.arch}</classifier>      
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>${pom.groupId}</groupId>
      <artifactId>CiscoJCEJNI</artifactId>
      <version>1.00</version>
      <classifier>${os.family}-${os.arch}</classifier>      
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>package-all</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <descriptors>
        <descriptor>src/main/assembly/dist-jar.xml</descriptor>
          </descriptors>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins> 
  </build> 
</project>
```

Assembler:

```
<assembly
  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">
  <id>${os.family}-${os.arch}</id>
  <formats>
    <format>jar</format>
  </formats>

  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>

  <dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
      <excludes>
    <exclude>org.slf4j:slf4j-simple</exclude>
    <exclude>org.slf4j:slf4j-api</exclude>
    <exclude>junit:junit</exclude>
      </excludes>
      <unpack>true</unpack>
      <useTransitiveDependencies>false</useTransitiveDependencies>
    </dependencySet>
  </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

I messed a bit with the maven-install-plugin install-file for the artifact, not much success yet though.

Comment: How does the pom fo the J-Dist project look like?

Comment: I did find 1 mistake looking through the log files and from your comment; i had packaging as a pom file and not a jar.  Its running again right now on our build server ...  Posted pom file in the edits for original comment

Comment: Pom error didn't fix problem; pom file above is what was used.  Still having issue download the classifier pom file, which doesn't exist

Comment: You have create a project CiscoJ-dist which is of type jar. But you would like to use it with classifier. Based on your posted pom i don't see a classifier. Only in case of the maven-assembly call. So can you post the assembly descriptor?

Comment: Edit to include assembly ... and I may as you point out have it misconfigured for the classifier.  I was looking over the doc at http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly-mojo.html and classifier is deprecated; recommended use is id.

Answer (score 0):

I think I determined that I had an invalid artifact in the file attempting to use the artifact.  I believe, and looks like it worked, that should be accessing it with the parent project as part of the group id/path.  Like below...

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.cisco.ciscossl.CiscoJ</groupId>
      <artifactId>CiscoJ-dist</artifactId>
      <classifier>${os.family}-${os.arch}</classifier>
      <version>1.00</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

khmarbaise, much appreciated to comments of the above.  Leaving open for now until further determine that this wasn't the valid answer.  At least for now I can see a valid dependency tree being picked up....

```
[INFO] Building test-CiscoJ-disk 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ test-CiscoJ-dist ---
[INFO] com.cisco.ciscossl:test-CiscoJ-dist:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.11:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] \- com.cisco.ciscossl.CiscoJ:CiscoJ-dist:jar:unix-amd64:1.00:compile
[INFO]    +- org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:jar:1.7.2:compile
[INFO]    \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.2:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```